# How to hook a target URL with my own resources in electron?

Tags: javascript, electron, chromium

I'm playing around with Electron and want to do the following:

- Use `BrowserWindow.loadURL()` to open `url_1`
- In the UI part of `url_1` that `BrowserWindow` renders, there's a link which points to another resource, let's say `url_2.html`
- When I click this link, normally my `BrowserWindow` would load `url_2.html`. However, I want my `BrowserWindow` not to actually go to load `url_2.html` from the internet, since I actually have another file, say, `url_3.html` in my app's resources. What I want to achieve is this: When `BrowserWindow` detects that `url_2.html` is going to be loaded, it will automatically load `url_3.html`.

I tried to step into "loadURL" in source code of Electron, but only got the following in `node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts`. There's no more JavaScript implementation.

```js
/**
 * Same as webContents.loadURL(url[, options]). The url can be a remote address
 * (e.g. http://) or a path to a local HTML file using the file:// protocol. To
 * ensure that file URLs are properly formatted, it is recommended to use Node's
 * url.format method: You can load a URL using a POST request with URL-encoded data
 * by doing the following:
 */
loadURL(url: string, options?: LoadURLOptions): Promise<void>;
```

How can I implement my requirements using Electron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `.d.ts` files are so-called "definition files", think of them like `.h` (header) files for C/C++ programs. Thus, you don't see any implementation.

Another approach which you could implement, given you have access to `url_1.html`, is to attach an event listener to all links pointing to `url_2.html` and change the link target to `url_3.html`, like so:

```
window.addEventListener ("load", () => {
    nodes = document.querySelectorAll ('a[href="url_2.html"]'); // (1)
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        nodes[i].addEventListener ("click", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault ();
            window.location.href = "url_3.html";                // (2)
    }
});
```

Two things need adjustment here: (1) is where the **exact** URL of `url_2.html` needs to be inserted, namely exactly as it has been specified in the `a` elements, and (2) is where you need to insert the full URL to your (local) `url_3.html`.

On the other hand, if you don't have access to the `url_1.html` file, possibly because it is used on a server and cannot be modified because it is also used through "normal" browsers which need to load `url_2.html`, you can manipulate the navigation process from the Electron main thread, like so:

```
webcontents = win.webContents;
webcontents.on ("will-navigate", (e, url) => {
    if (url === "url_2.html") {              // (1)
        e.preventDefault ();
        webcontents.loadURL ("url_3.html");  // (2)
    }
});
```

The above assumes that your `BrowserWindow` object is named `win`. Also, you need to modify two things here also: (1) is where you will need to put the full, exact URL to your `url_2.html`, namely exactly how Chromium would load it, and (2) is where you need to put your full URL to `url_3.html`.

Comment: if i'm understanding, this isn't sutiable if you need a generic redirection? for instance, in my case I have various javascript files in different node_modules packages, and my main page can't find them because it doesn't know they aren't in the same path as the main module.  what i need is something to translate a page name to point it to the correct path for that page.

Comment: @Michael If they're in Node.js packages, you can simply `require ()` them. But I suggest you ask a whole new question, describing your problem in detail.