# How to hook file requests from javascript in Electron to produce the correct path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm creating an Electron app and in the process am trying to use some existing javascript and other files (css and other resources).  My code is spread out across a number of packages, each package containing various of these files.  Outside of Electron these files would be served from a server which provides a mapping from a flat list of files to the paths to each of these files and I am trying to implement similar "server-side" functionality in Electron's "back end", if there is such a thing.

Since Electron is getting these files from the `file://` protocol it is not finding most of these files because everything is resolving relative to the path of the current javascript file and these files do not know about each other and thus cannot specify a hard-coded path.

Is there some mechanism in Electron to hook requests for files so that I can provide the path for it to look at?  In my server-side code I do something where I have an object which maps file names to the paths they are in, and I feel like the solution would similarly be to intercept requests and tell Electron where to look for each file.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479171/how-to-hook-a-target-url-with-my-own-resources-in-electron) but the solution offered there won't work for me because my web app is a bit too dynamic and the requests are coming from deep in the code, not some user interface element I could trap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by intercepting the file protocol handler.  If you have set up your file mappings into an object like so:

```
files = {
    "file1.js": "/path/to/file1.js",
    "file2.js": "/path/to/file2.js",
    // etc.
}
```

Then in the createWindow function you will insert this code immediately after you instantiate the new BrowserWindow:

```
protocol.interceptFileProtocol("file", (req, cb) => {
    var file = req.url.split("/")
    file = file[file.length-1]
    if (files[file]) {
        console.log(`intercepting ${file} => ${files[file]}`)
        cb({path:files[file]})
    }
})
```

Note: The `protocol` references a `const` that you get from requiring electron, e.g. something like this:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, protocol} = require("electron")
```

This code assumes that the file names are unique and are the only part of the path that matters.  So for instance, not matter what path the code thinks "file1.js" is in, in the above example it will be redirected to `/path/to/file1.js`.  If the requested file doesn't exist then the behavior is undefined and probably nothing will load.